# Where would I ask a question requiring multiple languages?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I recently had a question about "What languages other than English distinguish 'poison' and 'venom'", but I can't think of a site on which this question is appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/). That would seem to be on-topic there.